# The requested Payment Method is not available When creating an order

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, rest-api

We get `The requested Payment Method is not available` error when we try to create order using REST api.payment method works fine with all online orders and i am using given api.

> Request- (Put)

```
http://MyHost.com/rest/V1/carts/67/order 
json-{ "paymentMethod": { "method": "free"}}
```

> Response-

```
{
  "message": "The requested Payment Method is not available.",
  "trace": "#0 /chroot/home/folder/html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(337): Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment->importData(Object(Magento\\Framework\\DataObject))\n#1 [internal function]: Magento\\Quote\\Model\\QuoteManagement->placeOrder(67, Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment))\n#2 /chroot/home/folder/html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(307): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#3 /chroot/home/folder/html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(216): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->processApiRequest()\n#4 /chroot/home/folder/html/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#5 /chroot/home/folder/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#6 /chroot/home/folder/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#7 /chroot/home/folder/html/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http))\n#8 {main}"
}
```

Did I miss something About setting ?

and i am using following steps to create an order.

**Create customer-**

curl -g -X POST "$base_url/index.php/rest/V1/customer" \ -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \ -H "Content-Type:application/json" \ -d '{"customer":{"email":"sunny.kumar@web.biz","firstname":"sunny","lastname":"kumar","store_id":1,"website_id":1,"addresses":[{"region":{"region_code":"WA","region":"Washington","region_id":62},"region_id":62,"country_id":"US","street":["1401 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington"],"telephone":"1 202-628-9100","postcode":"DC 20004","city":"Washington","firstname":"sunny","lastname":"kumar","prefix":"Mr."},{"region":{"region_code":"WA","region":"Washington","region_id":62},"region_id":62,"country_id":"US","street":["1401 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington"],"telephone":"1 202-628-9100","postcode":"DC 20004","city":"Washington","firstname":"sunny","lastname":"kumar","prefix":"Mr.","default_shipping":true,"default_billing":true}],"disable_auto_group_change":0}}'

**Create cart-**

Creates an empty cart and quote for a specified customer.

curl -g -X POST "$base_url/index.php/rest/V1/customer/{customerId}/carts/" \ -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"

**Add Product To Cart**

curl -g -X POST "$base_url/index.php/rest/V1/carts/67/items" \ -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \ -H "Content-Type:application/json" \ -d '{ "cartItem": { "quote_id": "67", "sku": "Test-Sku", "qty": 2 } }'

**Get Payment Method**

curl -g -X GET "$base_url/index.php/rest/V1/carts/67/payment-information" \ -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"

response-
[
  {
    "code": "free",
    "title": "No Payment Information Required"
  }
]

**Place Order**

curl -g -X PUT "$base_url/index.php/rest/V1/carts/67/order" \ -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \ -H "Content-Type:application/json" \ -d ' { "method": { "method": "free" } } '

Comment: please provide the more data what parameters you are passing to create order what you are passing in body

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal please see my update question.

Answer (score 1):

try this for payment method :

GET "$base_url/index.php/rest/V1/carts/67/payment-methods

response :
[
  {
    "code": "checkmo",
    "title": "Check / Money order"
  }
]

Comment: still facing same issue requested-body '{ "paymentMethod": { "method": "checkmo"}} '

Comment: @vikas : did you enabled payment method From admin please check once because code provided by me its working fine

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently. The issue was with the country id. I was using US as country id for testing purpose, however my magento is set to work for another country. Make sure that you are using the same country code set in magento backend.